# BIRT's pie chart and additional data for each cell

Tags: java, charts, birt

I've got simple PieChart constructed in BIRT, now i need to add onclick action for values, so when user click he will be redirected.

Adding onclick action is simple:

```
PieSeries ps = (PieSeries) PieSeriesImpl.create();
ps.getTriggers().add(TriggerImpl.create(TriggerCondition.ONCLICK_LITERAL,
   ActionImpl.create(ActionType.INVOKE_SCRIPT_LITERAL,
   ScriptValueImpl.create("gotoURL(arguments);"))));
```

now if user click on chart value a javascript function will be called and some parameters will be passed (categoryData, valueData,valueSeriesName, legendItemText, legendItemValue, axisLabel)

But i need to pass additional value that is known only on chart generation time (when I'm creating dataSet scripts), and it's based on two other values recordID from CellObject(object that have cell value) and stringKey from LabelObject (object that have Label name).

How can I pass this value to piechart?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:
http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/1474-client-side-script-to-show-detail-rows-from-chart-and-table/